# Rails RSpec Controller Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test that a `Subscription` was actually created as part of my `Company#create` controller method:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CompaniesController, :type => :controller do

  before do
    user = build(:user, :company => nil)
    login_with(user)
  end

  it "should have a subscription" do
    company = build(:company).attributes
    terms_accepted = { terms_accepted: true }
    @company_params = company.merge(terms_accepted)
    post :create, { company: @company_params }
    # I need to expect something here like company.subscription.exists?
  end
end
```

I've already created a test to verify a `company` is created which is contained in the 4 lines I currently have in the test above.

I have a `company` factory that also creates a `subscription`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    name "ACME Test"
    address_1 "123 Shady Lane."
    address_2 "Suite 400"
    city "Testville"
    state "Somewhere"
    zip_code "12345"
    has_payment_plan false
    stripe_id "cus_34d434343e4e3e3"
    locked false
    association :subscription
  end
end
```

And... I have a `subscription` factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :subscription do
    company_id 1
    trial true
    custom nil
    convert_date nil
    per_device_price 3
    trial_expires 5.days.from_now
    freemium false
  end
end
```

And here is my `Company#create` controller method... *(yes, it has alot of bloat, which I'm eventually moving to the model once I have a base-line of tests that work)*:

```
def create
    company = Company.new(company_params)
    user = current_user

    if company.save && params[:terms]  == "1"
      user.company = company
      accepted = true
      user.terms_accepted = accepted
      user.save
      Subscription.create(company_id: user.company.id, trial: true, charge_date: Date.today + 1.month, per_device_price: 5.00, trial_expires: Date.today + 5.days)
      device = Device.create(is_registered: true, registered_date: Date.today, company_id: user.company.id, name: user.company.name, is_sent: true, sent_date: Date.today)
      location = Location.create(company_id: user.company.id, identifier: device.identifier, name: company.name)
      device.serial_number = device.identifier
      NewDevice.new_device(user, device).deliver
      flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "You did not accept the terms of service."
      sign_out(user)
      redirect_to root_path
    end  
end
```

I thought I was on the right track by just checking to see if `Subscription was increased by 1`, as I did with my `Company#create` test, but that's returning:

```
Failures:

  1) CompaniesController should have a subscription
     Failure/Error:
       expect {
         post :create, { company: @company_params }
       }.to change(Subscription, :count).by(1)

       expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

Am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: can you debug after user.save? and run Subscription.create(...) to see the output?

Comment: Can I do that within the test environment context?  I'm using `guard`.

Comment: I think you could use pry-remote. Otherwise, just run rake test on a separate console with byebug after 'user.save'

Comment: `bundle exec rake test` -> Don't know how to build task 'test'

Comment: To clarify, you're saying add `Subscription.create!` to the last line of the current test?

Comment: replace Subscription.create(...) with Subscription.create!(...) in 'def create'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134499/discussion-between-godzilla74-and-gaston).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you don't pass `terms: '1'` as a request param in your test. Instead of that you pass `terms: true` (which isn't the same as '1') and also you put it inside the `company` `attributes` hash. So you need either replace the condition in your action to `if company.save && params[:terms] == true` or pass `'1'` in your test.

That should work

```
it "should have a subscription" do
  company = build(:company).attributes
  expect {
    post :create, { company: company, terms: '1' }
  }.to change(Subscription, :count).by(1)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your spec file `companies_controller_spec.rb` I would do something like this:

```
let(:valid_params) {
  attributes_for(:company).merge(terms_accepted: true)
}

context 'POST #create' do
  it 'creates a company' do
    expect do
      post :create, params: { company: valid_params }, session: {}
    end.to change(Company, :count).by(1)
  end

  it 'creates a subscription' do
    expect do
      post :create, params: { company: valid_params }, session: {}
    end.to change(Subscription, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

If the second spec fails, you'll need to troubleshoot why. You are not doing any error handling for the creation of Subscription, Device, or Location.

In addition there are several other problems with your `create` controller  method that are beyond the scope of your question. However, I assume you will find and address those as you work through the code.

Comment: So, even the first test, which I had passing now fails `creates a company`.

Comment: Ok, got around the problem by using `post :create, company: valid_params` to make the first test pass.  2nd still fails.

Comment: You'll need to discover why the `Subscription.create(company_id: user.company.id, trial: true, charge_date: Date.today + 1.month, per_device_price: 5.00, trial_expires: Date.today + 5.days)` line fails. There are many ways to do that. 1) assign it to a variable and check that it actually does the create. 2) Use [Pry](http://pryrepl.org/) to put a breakpoint in the code and run the failing line to see why it fails. 3) Use a logging statement to print out subscription.errors. 4) Check for exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with the low hanging fruit - instead of an "unwrapped" hacky TOS you can simply make it a virtual attribute of Company.

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  validates_acceptance_of :terms # makes a virtual attribute if no column exists
end
```

A major pain point in this controller is that you are doing a bunch of operations after you save the controller that should really be done before.

In Rails when you save a parent record the child records will also be saved. You can use this to simplify the logic of this controller:

```
def create
  company = Company.new(company_params)
  subscription = company.subscriptions.new(
    trial: true,  
    charge_date: 1.month.from_now, 
    per_device_price: 5.00, 
    trial_expires: 5.days.from_now
  )
  # ...

  if company.save
    # ...
  else
    # ...
  end  
end
```

You can use this together with `validates_associated` so that you would get direct feedback. You should be able to test it then by:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe CompaniesController, :type => :controller do

  before do
    user = build(:user, :company => nil)
    login_with(user)
  end

  describe "#create" do
    let(:valid_attributes) { attributes_for(:company, terms: true) }
    let(:invalid_attributes) { attributes_for(:company, terms: false) }

    describe "with valid attributes" do
      it "creates a company" do
        expect {
          post :create, { company: valid_attributes }
        }.to change(Company, :count).by(+1)
      end
      it "creates a subscription" do
        expect {
          post :create, { company: valid_attributes }
        }.to change(Subscription, :count).by(+1)
        expect(Subscription.last.company).to eq Company.last
      end
    end

    describe "with invalid attributes" do
      it "does not create a company" do
        expect {
          post :create, { company: attributes }
        }.to_not change(Company, :count)
      end
      it "does not creates a subscription" do
        expect {
          post :create, { company: invalid_attributes }
        }.to_not change(Subscription, :count)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However I can't help but wonder if part of this logic really should be attached to the user and not the company - if you are keeping track of login devices and locations it should be done in your `SessionsController` or wherever the user signs in.